# Retrieving data from one-to-many associated table with ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an **asp.net core mvc 3.1** project. There is user management in this project. The user table and the department table are linked by one to many relationships (I'm not sure I did this correctly). I can get the user registration smoothly. However, I can not show the **department name** in the table that I use on the front side according to the **departmentId** value I added while getting the registration of the user from the department table that I have established.

I need your support in this regard.
**Note:** I'm using **ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging**

**AppDbContext**

```cs
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AppUser> Kullanicilar { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Firma> Firmalar { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Departman> Departmanlar { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            //kullanıcı tablolarında kullanmak istemediğim tablalrı kaldırma
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
                .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber)
                .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
        }
    }
```

**AppUser Model**

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        public  string Ad { get; set; }
        public  string Soyad { get; set; }
        public  string Gorevi { get; set; }
        public  string Image { get; set; }
        public  string GsmNo { get; set; }
        public  string KanGrubu { get; set; }
        
        public string DepartmanId { get; set; }
        public Departman Departman { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Departman> DepartmanListesi { get; set; }
    }
```

**Departman Model**

```cs
public class Departman
    {
        [StringLength(450)]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Departman Adı")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**RegisterViewModel**

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email Adres:")]
        [Remote(action:"IsEmailInUse", controller:"Account")]
        [ValidEmailDomain(allowedDomain:"bakirlar.com.tr", ErrorMessage = "Sadece bakirlar.com.tr uzantılı email adresi ile kayıt olabilirsiniz.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Şifre:")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Şifre Onayı:")]
        [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage = "Şifreler Eşleşmiyor!")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "Ad:")]
        public string Ad { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "Soyad:")]
        public string Soyad { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "Görevi:")]
        public string Gorevi { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "GSM No:")]
        public string GsmNo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "Kan Grubu:")]
        public string KanGrubu { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan zorunludur!")]
        [Display(Name = "Departman:")]
        public string DepartmanId { get; set; }
        public Departman Departman { get; set; }
    }
```

**AccountController**
**Action => AddNewUser**

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewUser(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Departman newDepartmanId = departmanRepository.GetById(model.DepartmanId);

                var user = new AppUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Ad = model.Ad,
                    Soyad = model.Soyad,
                    GsmNo = model.GsmNo,
                    Gorevi = model.Gorevi,
                    KanGrubu = model.KanGrubu,
                    Departman = newDepartmanId,
                };

                user.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ListUsers", "Administration");
                    }
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**AdministrationController**
**Action => ListUsers**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ListUsers(string filter, int page = 1, int satir = 10, string sortExpression = "UserName")
        {
            ViewBag.SayfaAdi = "Kullanıcı Listesi";

            var item = userManager.Users.AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                item = item.Where(p => p.UserName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()));
            }

            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(item, satir, page, sortExpression, "UserName");

            model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"filter", filter}
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

**View => ListUsers**

```html
@model PagingList<AppUser>
<div class="container-fluid page__heading-container">
    <div class="page__heading d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="flex">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/"><i class="material-icons icon-20pt">home</i></a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@ViewBag.SayfaAdi</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="m-0">Kullanıcı Listesi</h1>
        </div>
        <a asp-action="AddNewUser" asp-controller="Account" class="btn btn-success ml-3 text-white">Yeni Kullanıcı<i class="material-icons icon-16pt text-white">add</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Tablo Arama Alanı Başlangıç-->
<div class="card card-form d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row">
    <form method="get" class="card-form__body card-body-form-group flex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filter_name">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                    <div class="search-form form-control search-form--light input-group-lg">
                        <input id="filter" name="filter" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adına Göre Ara..." value="@Model.RouteValue["filter"]">
                        <button id="clear" class="btn btn-hover-primary" type="button" role="button" onclick="ClearTextBox()">Temizle</button>
                    </div>
                    <button style="display:none" type="submit"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!--Tablo Arama Alanı Bitiş-->
<!--Tablo Başlangıcı-->
<div id="view-all">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ViewAllUsers", Model)
</div>
<!--Tablo Bitişi-->
<!--Pagination-->
<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <vc:pager paging-list="@Model" />
    </div>
</div>
<!--Pagination-->
```

**PartialView => _ViewAll**

```html
@model PagingList<AppUser>

<div class="card">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table mb-0 thead-border-top-0 table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 30px;">#ID</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Kullanıcı Adı ve Email</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Ad Soyad</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Departman</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Görevi</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">GSM No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">İşlem</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="list" id="tumKullanicilar">
                <!--Veriler Başlangıç-->
                @foreach (var user in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="badge badge-light">#@user.Id</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>@user.Email</td>
                        <td>@user.Ad @user.Soyad</td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach (var departman in user.DepartmanListesi)
                            {
                                @departman.Name
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>@user.Gorevi</td>
                        <td>@user.GsmNo</td>
                        <td class="text-center" style="width: 95px;">
                            <button onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Account",new {id=user.Id},Context.Request.Scheme)','Kullanıcı Bilgilerini Düzenle')" class="btn btn-primary p-1"><i class="material-icons icon-16pt text-white">edit</i></button>
                            <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@user.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
                                <button type="submit" value="X" class="btn btn-danger p-1"><i class="material-icons icon-16pt text-white">delete_forever</i></button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                <!--Veriler Bitiş-->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[SQL Server DB Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ODFo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The table AppUser only store DepartmanId when finished registration.

If you want to show Departman Info, you should add Departman to each AppUser.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ListUsers(string filter, int page = 1, int satir = 10, string sortExpression = "UserName")
        {
            ViewBag.SayfaAdi = "Kullanıcı Listesi";

            var item = userManager.Users.AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                item = item.Where(p => p.UserName.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()));
            }

  //****   add Departman to each User
 //    var userList = item.ToList();
//     for (int i = 0; i < userList.Length; i++)
//       userList[i].Departman = departmanRepository.GetById( userList[i].DepartmanId);


            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(item, satir, page, sortExpression, "UserName");

            model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"filter", filter}
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. I applied your suggestion bu i get an error.

Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IQueryable<AppUser>

Comment: item is IEnumerable, what doesn't support indexing concept. Convert it to List.                                                                                                               
 //    var userList = item.ToList();